# Error: "missing revert data in call exception" with ethers5.6.9

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, smartcontracts, ethers.js

TypeScript with Ethers Version ethers@5.6.9

Hello !!

Error: "missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string"

El Error se produce en la funcion "V2Router.getAmountsOut"

Code:
...
import * as UniswapV2Router from "../../../abis/UniswapV2Router02.json";
...

export const getPriceOnUniV2 =
async ( tokenIn: string, tokenOut: string, amountIn: BigNumber, routerAddress: string ): Promise => {

const V2Router = new ethers.Contract( routerAddress, UniswapV2Router.abi, maticProvider );

const amountsOut = await V2Router.getAmountsOut(1000, [tokenIn, tokenOut]);

if (!amountsOut || amountsOut.length !== 2) {

return getBigNumber(0); }

return amountsOut[1]; };

Log:

[WARN] error - Error en GetPrice: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string

Similars: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/2849

Answer (score 4):

The result of calling a function that existed in the ABI I was using, but not in the actual contract deployed on the Blockchain. In other words, I supplied the wrong contract address when I created the contract using new ethers.Contract(address, ABI, signer)

Answer (score 0):

One of the cause may be the Rpc Endpoint, try changing your rpc endpoint to the API_KEY only. Like your Your URL would be something like "https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/YOUR_API_KEY", try it only with YOUR_API_KEY.

This also happens when wrong arguments are passed in your contract methods. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630777/21054192) for more info